# Python urlopen "expected string or buffer"

Tags: python, rss

I am getting the "expected string or buffer" error in my simple python file. I am trying to get the titles of reddit articles written down.

```
from urllib import urlopen
import re


worldNewsPage = urlopen("https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/")

collectTitle = re.compile('<p class="title"><a.*>(.*)</a>')

findTitle = re.findall(collectTitle, worldNewsPage)

listIterator = []
listIterator[:] = range(1,3)

for i in listIterator:
    print findTitle
    print
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
worldNewsPage = urlopen("https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/")
```

to

```
worldNewsPage = urlopen("https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/").read()
```

Also [don't use `regex` to parse `html`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1219006). You can use  [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

Urlopen is an object so you have to call the method read to get the contents you downloaded (like files).